# How to have an instance of CoreWCF.Channels.TransportBindingElement?

Tags: wcf, .net-core, upgrade

I have a legacy code written by .NET 4.7.2 which should be upgraded to netstandard2.0. Here is the legacy code:

```
TransportBindingElement bindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement
{
    RequireClientCertificate = true,
    AllowCookies = false,
    AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
    BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
    DecompressionEnabled = true,
    ExtendedProtectionPolicy = new ExtendedProtectionPolicy(
        PolicyEnforcement.Always,
        ProtectionScenario.TransportSelected,
        null),
    HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
    KeepAliveEnabled = true,
    ManualAddressing = false,
    MaxBufferPoolSize = MaxBufferPoolSize,
    MaxBufferSize = MaxBufferSize,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = MaxReceivedMessageSize,
    MaxPendingAccepts = 0,
    ProxyAuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous,
    TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
    UseDefaultWebProxy = true
};
```

Since the `TransportBindingElement` class is an abstract and `HttpsTransportBindingElement` is not defined in CoreWCF, the question is: what is the alternative solution for the above code to migrate to netstandard2.0 using CoreWCF?

Comment: You can check out this tutorial on [upgrading a WCF service to .NET 6 using CoreWCF.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrading-a-wcf-service-to-dotnet-6/)

Comment: Did you find a way? I can see HttpsTransportBindingElement exist in CoreWCF.